# Should I use a single class to put SQLAlchemy table specifications and my business logic?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a class Contract to represent my contracts:

.../mypackage/Contract.py

```
class Contract:

    # setter and getters.

    def isValid( self, contract_number=None ):
        #code

    def cancelTheContract( self, contract_number=None ):
        # code
```

And my SQLAlchemy Contract class:

.../mypackage/orm.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

db = create_engine( 'mysql://myuser:mypasswd@localhost/mydatabase' )

contracts = Table( 'contracts', MetaData( bind = None ) )

class Connection:

    def connect( self ):
        Session = sessionmaker( bind = db )
        session = Session()
        return session

class Contract( Base ):
    __tablename__ = 'contracts'

    id = Column( Integer, primary_key = True )
    type = Column( String )
    price = Column( Float )
```

So...

Would be ok to merge both Contract classes in a single one?

If not, I have to instantiate a class specific for the database table and another class specific for the business logic, so when I have to deal with database data, manipulate it and put it back, I have to deal with two objects that are basically the thing.

Well... I guess I'm missing some important concept here.

What should I read to understand better about my question implications?

Thanks!
Gio

Comment: You should read about [classical mapping](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_styles.html). Hopefully it will help you understand that the mapped class is not special, so you can put pretty much anything you want in there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the philosophy of ORMs is to map physical tables to business entity objects, so it is best practice to combine your two classes. SQLA attributes manage the persistent fields of your entity and you can encapsulate all the business logic in that class per standard object-oriented modeling techniques.